# Add parameterized method to groovy class?

Tags: groovy

In groovy I can add a method to a class:

```
g.metaClass.bye = { println "Goodbye, $name" }
g.bye()
```

How can I add a method with parameters. Something like `bye(int a, int b)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add parameters to your closure

```
g.metaClass.bye = { int a, int b ->
    a + b
}
```